# Pandas to_sql() inserting index

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using Pandas 0.18.1, and while fiddling with this code,

```
import pd

def getIndividualDf(item):
    var1 = []
    # ... populate this list of numbers
    var2 = []
    # ... populate this other list of numbers

    newDf = pd.DataFrame({'var1': var1, 'var2': var2})
    newDf['extra_column'] = someIntScalar
    yield newDf

dfs = []
for item in someList:
    dfs.append(getIndividualDf(item))

resultDf = pd.concat(dfs)
resultDf['segment'] = segmentId # this is an integer scalar

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://'+user+':'+password+'@'+host+'/'+dbname)
resultDf.reset_index().to_sql('table_name', engine, schema="schema_name", if_exists="append", index=False)
```

I was getting this exception:

> (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "index" of relation "table_name" does not exist

Indeed, there is no such column in the table, only because there is no such explicit column in the data frame. Which is why it's weird.

Running

```
print(list(resultDf))
```

just before the `to_sql()` call, yields

> ['var1', 'var2', 'extra_column', 'segment']

Removing `index=False` from the `to_sql()` call changes the error to this:

> (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "level_0" of relation "table_name" does not exist

I am puzzled. How do I get rid of `index` column?

**Update**
`print(resultDf.head())` yielded this information:

```
     var1       var2  extra_column  segment
0       8   0.101653    2077869737   201606
1       9   0.303694    2077869737   201606
2      10   0.493210    2077869737   201606
3      11   0.661064    2077869737   201606
4      12   0.820924    2077869737   201606
```

Comment: try not reset_index() and add the index=False to the to_sql() call, also can you show us resultDF.head()

Comment: resultDF.head() starts off with a zero-index based column without a name, and continues with all of the named columns that are of interest to me. I'll post a sample in the question. Thanks for trying to help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need not to reset the index before writing to sql such has:

```
resultDf.to_sql('table_name', engine, schema="schema_name", if_exists="append", index=False)
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I still don't understand why reset_index() would affect the explicit index=False, but at this point I'm too tired to ask such questons, and am just happy that I can finally move forward with my data analysis ^_^

Comment: @AlexanderMP when you reset index, in creates a columns called level_0 and populate it with the index.